# How does というと work here?

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a dialogue between me and my language partner.
For full context, I attach the full block about the topic "Your name (anime)" we were talking about at that point:

> 「君の名は」は、DVDを買って、家で観ました。海外での「ジブリアニメ」の定義はよくわかりませんが、日本で「ジブリ映画」というと、スタジオジブリが製作したアニメ映画のことで、その数はそれほど多くはありません。
>   http://nendai-ryuukou.com/article/030.html
>
> でも「君の名は」は日本でもとても評判がよく、私もよくできていると思いました。ratwimps の歌を効果的に使い、テンポよく進んでいくのが良かったですね。
>   アンドレアスさんは字幕で観たのですか。私は、この映画では日本語の特性がよく表れていると思いました。男の子の一人称は「オレ」、女の子を呼ぶときの二人称は「おまえ」ですが、女の子の一人称は「私」、男の子を呼ぶときの二人称は「あなた」です。入れ替わっているとき、もちろん声や仕草でも区別がつきますが、どの人称を使うかでもすぐにわかるのです。画面に顔が映っていないときも同じです。
>   外見が女の子でも、「オレ・・・」とつぶやいたら、中身は男の子ですよね。
>   人称について話すと長くなるので、ここでやめておきます。

The sentence in question (Here she responded to my personal experience with the anime "your name", because I told her that I first thought it was a ghibli anime due to the high quality of the animation.):

> 「君の名は」は、DVDを買って、家で観ました。海外での「ジブリアニメ」の定義はよくわかりませんが、日本で「ジブリ映画」というと、スタジオジブリが製作したアニメ映画のことで、その数はそれほど多くはありません。
>   http://nendai-ryuukou.com/article/030.html

My attempt at translation:

> "Having bought 'your name' as a DVD, I watched it at home. I don't know the defintion of 'ghibli anime' in foreign countries, but in japan, speaking of ghibli anime, out of the anime which studio ghibli has made, the amount/number isn't many to that extent."

So, I'm very confused about there being the term 'ghibli anime' and the phrase 'movie which studio ghibli has produced' in the same sentence ^^ Following the description of というと [here](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-toiuto-toieba-toittara/) I assumed that the sentence was built like that to introduce the term 'ghible anime' first, and then explain that the number of anime produced by studio ghibli isn't very high.

I also had problems translating のことで. I basically used the meaning of の中で but it doesnt seem to fit. Furthermore, the way I translated それほど多く is supposed to mean "(there are) not that many", but I did it in this very obstructed way to show that I'm very skeptical about this interpretation. I did not find それほど多く as an entry on jisho as a set phrase, so I put put it together from its isolated parts.

Comment: In this context というと means nothing more than its literal translation 'if you say'. のこと is 'about'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assumed that the sentence was built like that to introduce the term 'ghible anime' first, and then explain that the number of anime produced by studio ghibli isn't very high.

I think your understanding is correct.

The というと literally means "If you say~~", and ～のことで (で is the continuative form of the copula だ・です) means "refers to~~".

日本でXXというと、YYのことだ/です。
= *lit.* In Japan, if you say XX, it refers to YY.
→ In Japan, XX refers to YY.

「それほど～～ない」 means *lit.* "not ~~ to that extent" → "not so~~" "not very~~".
So 「それほど多くありません」 means "~~is not that many" "the number is not so large".

> 日本で「ジブリ映画」というと、スタジオジブリが製作したアニメ映画のことで、その数はそれほど多くはありません。

"In Japan, 'Ghibli films' refers to the anime films created by Studio Ghibli, and its number is not so large (i.e. there aren't that many of them)."

Answer (score 1):

> 「ジブリ映画」というと、スタジオジブリが製作したアニメ映画のことで、その数はそれほど多くはありません。

「ジブリ映画」というと、スタジオジブリが製作したアニメ映画のことで means 「ジブリ映画」の定義は、スタジオジブリが製作したアニメ映画です。そして.
*The definition of 'ghibli anime' is a 'movie which studio ghibli has produced', and*

Answer (score 1):

Also, your interpretation of それほど多く・・・ありません is basically correct, albeit wordy. It just means "not that many."

As for のこと, to add to what mackygoo said, のこと and ということ are phrases that occur *very* frequently at the end of a definition. In conversational English we sometimes use "a/the thing" in a definition, e.g.,

> A steering wheel is *the thing* you use to turn a car while driving.

That's essentially what のこと means in Japanese, but it fits naturally in almost any definition (including, incidentally, definitions of concrete objects that would be considered もの).